# Implementing vector of structs and map having pointers to the struct

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I am having 3 data structures: a Queue Node (`struct`), a `vector` of Queue Nodes and a `map` having a key as a string and a pointer to a Queue Node. They are defined as follows:

---

Queue Node:

```
struct QNode{
    int32_t index;
    int32_t count;
};
```

Vector:

```
vector<QNode> n;
```

Map:

```
map<string, QNode*> QueuePointerMap;
```

---

Whenever I create a node, I insert it into the vector and store the pointer to the node just created in map with the key as a unique string. I use the following code to do so:

```
n.push_back(QNode());           
int insertIndex = n.size();
n[insertIndex-1].index = index-1;       
n[insertIndex-1].count = 1;
cout << "***************************\n";
cout << "Insert index: " << insertIndex << "\n"; 
cout << "n[insertIndex -1].index: " << n[insertIndex -1].index << "\n";
cout << "n[insertIndex -1].count: " << n[insertIndex -1].count << "\n";                     
cout << "***************************\n";
QueuePointerMap[uniqStr] = &(n[insertIndex-1]);
cout << "Address of N: " << &(n[insertIndex-1]) << "\n\n";
```

Whenever I insert a node in the vector, it gets stored properly in the vector and the map but I face a problem after inserting a new node. Whenever I insert a new value in the vector (and the map), and if I try to fetch the previous values, I get different values than what had been stored. I use the following code for retrieving my values:

```
map<string, QNode*>::iterator it1;
it1=QueuePointerMap.find(uniqStr);
if(it1 == QueuePointerMap.end()){
    cout << "\n Not Found \n";
}
else{
    QNode * n1 = it1->second;
    cout << "Value of N1: " << n1 ;
    cout << "\t Index: "<< (n1->index) << "\n Count: " << (n1->count) << "\n";
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting different values of the index and count. I guess I am doing something wrong during insertion but I am not able to figure out what's the problem. I would really appreciate, if anyone helps me understand that and fix that. Thanks.

Comment: Where/when is the `uniqstr` value set before using it as a key for the `QueuePointerMap`?

Comment: I am getting it from the user and making sure that its unique. If its not, the above operations don't happen.

Comment: Try temporarily storing the pointer values in another structure and/or step through slowly with the debugger and track the pointer values and QNode struct internals.  Keep in mind that the `[]` operator for a vector returns a reference to the element at that position. [std::vector::operator\[\]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you insert a new value in the vector the vector might or might not reorganize it's inner structures (relocating objects to different memory locations, etc...), so the old pointers you have obtained from elements of the vector might or might not be invalid ...

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/ says:

> If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references related to the container are invalidated.

Comment: You could map to the index ... map<string, int> QueueIndexMap;

Comment: @TheRookierLearner, if you know the number (N) of values you will put in the vector beforehand, you can call `vector.reserve(N)`. Then it will not be resize before that number is surpassed.

Comment: Mapping to the vector index instead of the element pointer might be much easier to maintain too.

Comment: @user2079303 - That's a lifesaver comment. :)